# Creating recursive list of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I want to create a function in Javascript which takes an array as argument and returns a list of objects. I have an array like this:

```
var arr= [10,20,30];
console.log(listFunction(arr));
```

The result should look like this:

```
{'val':10, 'restList':{'val':20, 'restList':{'val':30,'restList':'null'}}}
```

I have tried the forEach() function:

```
function listFunction(parentArr) {
    var listOfObjects = [];
    parentArr.forEach(function (entry, thisArg) {
        var singleObj = {}
        singleObj['val'] = entry;
        singleObj['restList'] = singleObj;
        listOfObjects[thisArg] = singleObj;
    });
    return listOfObjects;
};
```

Comment: Like a Linked-List or a functional Lisp-like list?

Comment: @ryanyuyu a list of node and successor. yes like Linked-list

Comment: It would be easier if the inner most `restList` should be `{}` instead of `null`.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use a recursive function:

```
function listFunction(arr){

   if(arr.length == 0){
       return null;
   }else{
       return {val: arr[0], restList: listFunction(arr.slice(1,arr.length))};
   }
 }
```

Comment: You can send the next position of array.  But you need create another function. function listFunction(arr, index)... And you need to increase the index  in each step.

Comment: Quick note:  `arr.length` isn't needed in the `slice` function.  If the second parameter is missing, it defaults to the length of the array.

Answer (score 0):

This is the Lisp-style recursive list algorithm.

```
var recursiveList = function (array) {
  return recursiveListHelper(arr, {});
};

var recursiveListHelper = function (array, obj) {
  if (array.length === 0) //stopping condition
    return null;

  var car = array[0];       //current element
  var cdr = array.slice(1); //rest of list
  obj = {val: car};
  obj.restList = recursiveListHelper(cdr, obj);
  return obj;
};
```

You mentioned that you wanted to avoid using `Array.slice`.  This solution uses array indexing instead of splitting into subarrays.

```
var recursiveIndexed = function (array) {
  return recursiveIndexedHelper(array, {}, 0);
};

var recursiveIndexedHelper = function (array, obj, index) {
  if (index == array.length)
    return null;

  var car = array[index];
  obj = {val: car };
  obj.restList = recursiveIndexedHelper(array, obj, index + 1);
  return obj;
};
```

A [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/wdgl7UtJgrbAEzDMC2eD?p=preview) as example.